# Complex exponentiation and its meaning

Tags: complex-numbers

We've come across exponential functions like 2^x ,3^x etc. Let me take one of them, say  **y=2^x** here; if we consider y to be the length of the tree after X years, it has a meaningful explanation, that is, say X=2, then we can say that after 2 years the tree was 4 times its original length, its length increasing by a factor of 2 compared to previous year's growth.  So what does a function like **y=2^ix**mean ? What does $i$ do here?

Comment: First, note that all exponents are the same, so really you can just focus on, say, $e^{ix}$. This sweeps out a circle in the complex plane.

Comment: $2^x$ has some power series $a_0+a_1x+\ldots$ Then we say let $2^{ix}=a_0+a_1(ix)+\ldots$ by analogy.

Comment: $2^{ix}$ (for x real)  is a complex number.  Complex Analysis is the analytic continuation of Real Analysis.  You would be amazed how real-world problems, analytically-continued into the complex domain are used to find real solutions.   The most beautiful example of analytic continuation in mathematics I think is the Riemann zeta function used in a proof of the Prime Number Theorem dealing with real numbers.

Comment: @Dominic  could u elaborate the meaning of the equation alone coz my knowledge of reimann zeta function is limited to just numberphile videos